# Regular expression to return text between nested brackets

Tags: python, regex

I am looking for a regular expression to return the text between nested brackets including the brackets. I am trying to do this in Python using the "re" library but I haven't succeeded so far. Many thanks for your help.

For instance:

```
INPUT = '{} abc {abc} cdf {"a":1, "b":"{"a":1, "b":{"a":1}}"}'

OUTPUT = ['{}', '{abc}', '{"a":1, "b":"{"a":1, "b":{"a":1}}"}']

import re

result = re.findall(**regex**, INPUT)

print(result)
```

Comment: `re.findall(r'\{[^}]*\}+', INPUT)`?

Comment: @Corralien, I found a case where your regex failed. INPUT = '{} abc {abc} cdf {"a":1, "b":"{"a":1, "b":{"a":1}}"}'. In this case the last parenthesis is missed - "} -.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're trying to match balanced bracket constructs, a clean and robust approach would be to use a regex engine that supports recursion, such as the [`regex`](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) module, and use the [`(?R)`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/recurse.html) pattern to recursively match balanced pairs of brackets:

```
import regex

INPUT = '{} abc {abc} cdf {"a":1, "b":"{"a":1, "b":{"a":1}}"}'
print(regex.findall(r'\{(?>[^{}]|(?R))*\}', INPUT))
```

This outputs:

```
['{}', '{abc}', '{"a":1, "b":"{"a":1, "b":{"a":1}}"}']
```

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing/CompetentBriskScans

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using a regex, you can also simply parse your input. Something like:

```
OUTPUT = []
lvl = 0
s = ''
for c in INPUT:
    if c == '{':
        lvl += 1
        s += c
    elif c == '}':
        lvl -= 1
        s += c
        if lvl == 0:
            OUTPUT.append(s)
            s = ''
    elif lvl > 0:
        s += c
```

Output:

```
# INPUT = '{} abc {abc} cdf {"a":1, "b":"{"a":1, "b":{"a":1}}"}'
>>> OUTPUT
['{}', '{abc}', '{"a":1, "b":"{"a":1, "b":{"a":1}}"}']
```